# How to get interconnected records in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a django model called Person and PersonRelation

```
class Person(model.Models):
     person_name = models.charfield(max_length=255, blank=False)
     person_address = models.charfield(max_length=255, blank = False)

class PersonRelation(model.Models):
     person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sibling_of')
     person_relation = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now Lets say:

```
SAM is Related to JOHN
SMITH is Related to JOHN
TOM is related to SMITH
```

How can I get all the related siblings from the database?

Required output of related siblings:
SAM - JOHN - SMITH - TOM

[image]

[image]

Comment: person  and person_relation are the same in ur model. Why do you have two fields? Have you checked your database?

Comment: because I want to create a sibling relation between two different persons.

Comment: @Neeraj I think `PersonRelation` is an association table for creating many to many relationship between persons.

Comment: I would suggest you to first make a rough Person and PersonRelation table with values and understand how what you have written this would look like in the database

Comment: @Neeraj I have added the database sketch.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what the input is here? A person for which you want all siblings? Or all persons that have at least one sibling?

Comment: @willem Lets say A is related to B and C is related to B. That means A and C are related too. I want the list of all related siblings of A. The output should be B - C. (input should be id of A). Should i use recursion??

Comment: @Quest: typically it means you store the *transitive closure* in the junction table in the first place.

Comment: @willem "you store the transitive closure in the junction table in the first place". Can you explain this? No idea what it is. Any link will be helpful. I solved it with recursion. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So I went with recursion :)

```
from relations.models import Person, PersonRelation
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

sibling_list = {"id_list":[], "sib_list":[]}

def related(person):

    direct_relation = PersonRelation.objects.filter(person__id = person.id)

    if direct_relation:
        for drel in direct_relation:
            if drel.person_relation.id not in sibling_list["id_list"]:
                sibling_list["id_list"].append(drel.person_relation.id)
                sibling_list["sib_list"].append(drel.person_relation)
            
            related(drel.person_relation)
        
    indirect_relation(person)

def indirect_relation(person):

    indirect_relation = PersonRelation.objects.filter(person_relation=person)

    if indirect_relation:
        for inrel in indirect_relation:
            if inrel.person.id not in sibling_list["id_list"]:
                sibling_list["id_list"].append(inrel.person.id)
                sibling_list["sib_list"].append(inrel.person)
                related(inrel.person)

    
def get_siblings(person_id):
    global sibling_list
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=person_id)
    related(person)
    sib_list = list(sibling_list["sib_list"])
    sibling_list = {"id_list":[], "sib_list":[]}

    return sib_list
```